# select only values below a treshhold while using join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Edit: Example is on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47eb42/3

**Longer Description of aim and old/bad working approach**

I want to select all groups, where the filesize of all items that are in the group, is below a treshold x. The group-filesize is created by adding up all values of the single items in the group (table 3). Sadly the filesize is saved in Table 1. So i currently use a multi-step-approach which seems not efficient.
I hope you can help me with some hints, if you think my current approach is ok, you may tell me too.

(Step-1) Currently i use php and a foreach-loop that gets me the items in Table **itemdata** which have Column **itemtype** = "Group". 
Foreach results

(Step-2) i loop through and search Table **groups** to find the **groupID** for the **itemid**.

(Step-3) i get the **itemId**s for all the items that are in the group from the table **groupItemRelation**.

(Step-4) i use the **itemId**s of the items that are in the group to get the **filesize** from Table-1 **itemdata** (again).

(Step-5) In php i calculate if the sum of the filesize-values of all group-items is exceeding the treshold. if it exceeds the treshold the groupdata i selected in Step-1 is not transfered to a "valid-results-array".

thanks in advance
greetings
Gerd

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help other people figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: In addition to what @GordonLinoff asked, cardinality of the relation between tables would help.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: learned something new. thanks for pointing out that i can use SQLFiddle, never used it. I edited the article above and put the link for the example inside: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47eb42/3